# Application.Restart() does not close the old one, but start a new one

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, kinect

C# WPF application, Kinect Application

Called from a Page, wanted to restart the whole application

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath);
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
```

Also does not close the old one.  Why is it?  Any hack I can do?  This is kind last-minute so I need a hack solution because I am going to demo in an hour.

Thanks.

Comment: @Silvermind - Environment.Exit would close the application and then nothing else would happen.  Besides `Application.Exit` should already close the application.

Comment: The Winforms Application object is not appropriate here, it cannot stop a WPF app.  Use the WPF Application.Shutdown() method instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Use This.
This Work On Wpf

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Environment.CurrentDirectory+"\\YourExeName");
Close();
```

Comment: Your suggested code does exactly the same thing the author's code does.